# server-to-server app review process for Instagram graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

I just migrated from the deprecated Instagram API to Facebook Graph API but I am not sure if I need to go through the app review process. All I do is display my Instagram photos in a carousel on my web site. The app review process on the FB developers site ask for a Privacy URL, a screencast and what else.

Thanks

Comment: rule of thumb: if it works and there is no warning, you don´t need a review. just stating the obvious :)